# Align equations at equality sign

Tags: align

I have followed the code from this answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211540/237717. The equations below are to be aligned at '=' signs but the alignment is not properly done. I need some help with my code. Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{align*}

$< f,g >$_{\mathcal{H}_K}    &=  \Sigma_{i=1}^n \Sigma_{j=1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j  < K(x, x_i), K(x,x_j)>_{\mathcal{H}_K}    \\

                                              &=  \Sigma_{i} \Sigma_{j} \alpha_i \alpha_j K(x_i, x_j) \\ 

                                              &= \alpha^T K \alpha
\end{align*}
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated don't use `<>` here use `\langle\rangle` they have the proper spacing. `<>` are relation symbols and thus give the wrong spacing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$ $` and **blank line** in `align*` environment.

(Edited by @daleif's comment)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\langle f,g \rangle_{\mathcal{H}_K} &=  \Sigma_{i=1}^n \Sigma_{j=1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j  \langle K(x, x_i), K(x,x_j)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_K} \\
&=  \Sigma_{i} \Sigma_{j} \alpha_i \alpha_j K(x_i, x_j) \\ 
&= \alpha^T K \alpha
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for the answer! 
It has happened before that if I do not leave a line after the line \begin{align*}, the output is not shown at all. Your code works perfect but I am still curious why the output could be completely missing in align and split environments, unless I break an empty line

Comment: You are not allowed to use the blank line in math environments. A blank line creates an error and the output is not displayed.